# What are good approaches of finding a successor to a set?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I am new to finding algorithms for a problem. The assignment I am working on involves adapting the Quick Union Algorithm. Here is the question:

Given a set of n integers S = {0, 1, ..., n−1} and a sequence of requests of the following form: Remove x from S. Find the successor of x: the smallest y in S such that y≥x. design a data type so that all operations (except construction) take logarithmic time or better in the worst case.

What is challenging for me is how to think through this problem. I know how the Quick Union Algorithm, but I still can't figure out a way to solve this. Are there any good books or other resources that help with giving the mental tools to solve problems like these?

Also, would this be the correct stack exchange to post this question? Not sure if this was a more of a computer science or math question.

Comment: Given, as you say, $S=\{\,0,1,\dots,n-1\,\}$, the successor of $x$ is $x+1$, unless $x=n-1$, in which case $x$ has no successor. Doesn't seem like much of a challenge, but maybe you meant something different from what you wrote (in which case, please edit the body of your question so it says what you actually meant to say).

Comment: The question is from a Coursera course. I didn't write it, but I see your point that the answer appears to be really obvious. I found a link with the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860950/union-find-successor-with-delete. Is there something in this link that I missed in the question? Knowing this would improve my understanding. Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe what's missing is some indication that the deletion operation is performed *repeatedly*, or that $S$ is a *subset* of $\{\,0,1,\dots,n-1\,\}$.